# Dijit.tree - Listing a directory on webserver

Tags: dojo

I would like to know if there is an easy way to list all the files in a directory on a webserver using Dojo's dijit.tree.

I suppose I could populate a datastore of the files using PHP, but that seems like a major pain and something that could be done much easier, I just can't think of anything else.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think web servers default to send you a list of all the files in the directory -- you'll have to use the FTP protocol to do it, not HTTP.  And the web server must be configured to accept FTP connections as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youll need to find a way to get the data from the server. Dojo can only handle things client-side

Answer (score 1):

Check out "dojox/data/demos/demo_FileStore_dojotree.html", that's one specific way requiring php support on your server